# WebStorm can't find globals like `Number` or `console` when using Deno

Tags: webstorm, deno

Any ideas of why that is? Do I need to tune the Deno settings in WebStorm?

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Did you [install the extension](https://deno.land/manual@v1.23.4/getting_started/setup_your_environment#jetbrains-ides)? Are you using customized [compiler options](https://deno.land/manual@v1.23.4/getting_started/configuration_file)?

Comment: I did install the extension and did not customise anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `tsconfig.json` in my project folder. I deleted that and also `.idea`. After doing that the problem disappeared.